# @if condition in SASS returns false when comparing to string

Tags: sass, angular7

I'm using SASS (.scss) for my angular 7 project. It has multiple theme. So I have to dynamically change global styles for each theme. But my @if condition returns false.

styles.scss:

```
@import "app/themes/Atlantis/master-style.atlantis.scss";


:root{
  --theme: false
}

@if var(--theme) == 'atlantis'{
  //@include master-style-atlantis;
  html {
    background:red; // sample code to check if my @if worked
  }
}
```

I add --theme prop with angular, app.component.ts:

```
 _document = document.querySelector('html');

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this._document.style.setProperty('--theme', 'atlantis');
 }
```

The html prop gets set like `style="--theme:atlantis;"` but the background color doesn't change. But if i use

```
@if var(--theme){
  //@include master-style-atlantis;
  html {
    background:red; // sample code to check if my @if worked
  }
}
```

it works. If its a true/false if will work. But comparing strings always returns false. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass is a **pre**-processor. By the time you apply the the `--theme: prop` on angular's `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, it has no relevant reference to that property change. So `@if var(--theme) == 'atlantis'` is expected to always return false since Sass runs long before that is set.

The reason your second "working" example "works" is because sass will indeed find the `var(--theme)` property there when it runs.

You might [read up](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/theming-angular-with-css-variables-3c78a5b20b24) a bit more on a more effective strategy to accomplish your goal. Hope this helps, cheers!